# Error " Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. " While trying to upload the app to google play for first time

Tags: android, flutter, release, google-play-console

I am tying to upload flutter app to google play for my first time, i have generated key and i have followed all steps that mention here  : https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android ,
but when i try to upload the release bundle to google play console i find this message appear to me :

#Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your App Bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again. Your App Bundle is expected to be signed with the certificate with fingerprint:
SHA1: xxxxx:xxxx
but the certificate used to sign the App Bundle you uploaded has fingerprint:
SHA1: xxxxx:xxxx

what can i do to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you build your app with the same release key? This error occurred when you try to update your app to play store with a different release key or with different `key.jks`

Comment: How did you enroll in Play Signing. Did you at any time upload an encrypted key to the Play Console? Did you use one of the advanced options?
You say this is the first time, but I suspect this isn't the first artifact you upload to the Play Console; did you upload an APK or App Bundle before then delete it?
The Google Play Console uses the certificate from the first artifact you upload as reference so it would not complain about a bad certificate if it was effectively the first upload ever for this app (unless you used one of the advanced Play Signing options).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the domain name you are using for your app is already used (com.yourdomain.yourapp), have you tried to change it?

Answer (score -1):

I think you are using debug signed build not Release signed build .Please confirm you have created release signed apk.

Comment: i use release signed